# How to install the newes LTS Version of NodeJS on a Raspberry Pi 400?

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi4

Hi I have downloaded the newest LTS Version of NodeJS but I don't know how I can install it.

When I use the

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

command I get the Message: NodeJS already is the newest Version (12.22.12~dfsg-1~deb11u4).
Is there any simple way to do it?

Comment: From your message, it looks like you already have that version of Node installed. Do you expect some other outcome?